# how to pass a vector of vectors into a function expecting a (raw) pointer to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector

I have a function that accepts a pointer to pointer to double:

```
void Foo(double ** m);  // expects a 3x3 matrix of doubles
```

Is it somehow possible, with appropriate casting and whatnot, to pass into this function either a std::vector of std::vectors of double or else an std::array of std::arrays of double?  If so, can someone please explain how?

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> v(3, std::vector<double>(3));
std::array<std::array<double, 3>, 3> a;
```

If the function accepted only a pointer to double, this would be possible.  (via either v.data() or a.data()).  But the pointer to pointer in the function interface makes me think that such a conversion may not be possible.

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: *Change an algorithm, and you change one part of your program. Change a data structure, and you change your whole program* - Some famous guy

Comment: Why don't you write your function so that it takes a 3x3 matrix of doubles and also use a 3x3 matrix of doubles as argument? Using a vector always implies you have a variable-size, which you obviously don't. Using a pointer to pointers can have many implications: ownership, intended use and `const` correctness, all of which have to be fixed or documented. Note also that converting `Foo()` to a function template could help you make this code compile, but strongly I doubt that it would make the code any better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't.** `double**` does not point to two-dimensional data. It points to an array of pointers to other arrays. Even if you could find a cast that compiled, the data layouts are simply incompatible.

Answer (score 7):

You have to build the array, by example:

```
double* a[3] = {v[0].data(), v[1].data(), v[2].data()};
Foo(a);
```

Comment: Fine if the bounds are known. The use of vector suggests otherwise.

Comment: As the question says the matrix is expected to 3x3, this could work as a quick fix.

Comment: Even if the bounds weren't known, it'd still be possible to use the vectors `size` property, right?

Comment: @RonThompson: And do what with it? Well, dynamically allocate yourself an array of pointers then fill it in a loop, I suppose.

Comment: And then reBox it when it comes back and give it back to your caller who is probably expecting a vector and free the memory. Nasty :(

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
double **p = new double *[v.size()];

for ( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) p[i] = v[i].data();

Foo( p );

delete [] p;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v =
    {
        { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 },
        { 4.4, 5.5, 6.6 },
        { 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 }
    };

    double **p = new double *[v.size()];

    double * ( std::vector<double>::*fn )() noexcept = &std::vector<double>::data;

    std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), p, std::mem_fn( fn ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); j++ ) std::cout << p[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    delete [] p;
}
```

The output is

```
1.1 2.2 3.3 
4.4 5.5 6.6 
7.7 8.8 9.9
```

Comment: Instead of dumping code, why not _explain_ your proposed solution? Also note that this copies everything.

Comment: Using RAII and `std::vector<double*> p(v.size())` and sending `ptrs.data()` would probably be preferential (not that any of this is a good idea to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

If it's just that one function that's mismatched, and it isn't called in an inner loop somewhere, (and you can't change its signature, like its part of an API you can't change): the only solution I can think of is to unbox your vector. Iterate over your vector and pull out all of the data and put it into an array and then feed that into your function.

Obviously, that's nasty in several ways, so if you have another option (notably, overloading the function to accept `vector`, then that's probably a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a design problem. Are you sure that `void Foo(double ** m);` expects a 3x3 matrix of doubles? If yes, than you need some wrapper function to convert `vector<vector<double> >` to `double**`. Any way it's the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T*> make_jagged_array( std::vector<std::vector<T>>& vec ) {
  std::vector<T*> retval;
  retval.reserve(vec.size());
  for(auto&& v:vec)
    retval.push_back(v.data());
  return retval;
}
```

will convert a `vector<vector<X>>` into a `vector<X*>`, and `vector<X*>.data()` returns you your `X**` you need.

Doing this for n dimensions would be amusing.